# How to delete a file in HDFS with random string in middle of the path

Tags: regex, scala, hadoop, hdfs

I have a file in HDFS named **AccountManager_S00B26_291141_NBMorbidity_2018-10-0201_17_32.258_TriggerFile.txt**

**2018-10-0201_17_32.258** in the above file name is random that needs to be ignored while deleting.

I tried the below code. But, It didn't work

```
    val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
    val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
    val src = new Path("AccountManager_S00B26_291141_NBMorbidity_{[0-9_.-]}*_TriggerFile.txt")
    hdfs.delete(src,true)
```

Comment: You'll need to list all files of the parent directory, iterate, check, then delete the matches. `Path` doesn't accept patterns

Comment: Any other simple way to delete such files?

Comment: Not really. You're already getting the filesystem, and there's just one method you're missing to list all files